# Select tag default selection blank item

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I declare several select items (about 4-5 dozen) by adding the following string to the page

```
"<select id='myidxxx'><option>" + default + "</option></select>"
```

And then add other elements later. The problem is, whether I add other elements or not, there is always a blank element selected at start. I can't get it to not have one, or to select the default value. I've tried

```
<option selected='selected'>
```

but with no success. How do I get this to list only the explicity added options (no blank line) and select the default entry?

EDIT: I am using IE8

Comment: So you're saying, if you have "<select><option>" +default+ "</option></select>" it will have a blank space selected? very bizarre. is default listed as an option underneath the blank space? If not, my guess would be that your "default" variable is undefined, so it prints it out as a blank space

Comment: Yes, it is listed. There is always the blank space at the top selected, then the default, and then any other options if I add them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I recommend that you create your elements in JS

Dynamically creating the select tag and its options is the way I would go about this. I am wonder though are you pulling data from a database or some other location that could be where you are getting the blank from.

Another possible solution it to iterate over the children of the option tag and not add it if it is a null or empty string.

```
for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i] != "" && options[i] != " ") {
        opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.innerText = options[i];
        opt.value = i;
        selectTag.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/V26P5/2/

Comment: Why do you suggest building it in JS?

Comment: I personally just try to avoid string concatenations where possible, just a habit.

Comment: @sdleihssirsh I am building it in JS, and when I add the other options (aside from the default) I iterate over an array and add each, which appears to work fine. The string concatenation shown in my question is where I put it together, and $('#div').html(string) is where I add it to the page.

Comment: I was pulling my default value from an array, and the rest of the items in the list were the rest of the array. For some reason the array was indexed from 1, so array[0] was causing the blank.

Answer (score 0):

What browser? In Chrome

```
<select><option>default</option></select>
```

shows 'default' as the pre-selected item